# WCF service installation and verification in IIS and/or WAS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, was

I gather there is nothing more to deploying services than installing the .svc file and associated binaries in a hosted directory under IIS, as described here (IIS):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

and here (WAS):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx

Two questions:

1. Is there any difference at all between these two scenarios for newer (>= 7.0) versions of IIS when using BasicHttpBinding?
2. Is there any way to view/test the WCF services hosted from within IIS?  IIS has this nice UI but as far as I can tell, you have to look at web.config and test the services using wcftestclient or use a browser to see if everything is working at any given point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference when using BasicHttpBinding in different versions of IIS. 
As far as I know there is no testing capability in IIS (TestWcfClient, unittests, ....)

Comment: do you mean that when you are hosting a service using BasicHttpBinding in IIS 7.0 or better, IIS and WAS are one and the same?  In other words, prior to IIS 7.0, they were different pieces of software, but in 7, they are somehow integrated.  The links I provided make it sound like the installation procedure is basically the same for IIS vs. WAS.  Does that mean they *are* the same?

Comment: WAS is a part of IIS, I even thought all sites hosted in IIS 7 are actually hosted in the WAS "not sure about that info" ;-)